# function returning blank on running

Tags: excel, vba

I have cell **H1** with certain values as `"10,1,7,8"` dynamically, another cell A1  calls the function as `=FindGrade(H1,"Books")`...when the values of e.g **B** is string like `"2,11"` then it shud check for both 2 and 11 existing in the cell H1 value also  but its not working...the result cell is blank...
I m trying to get result of function into cell  but the cell is always blank

idea is to check the string in chkcell with each value in A,B,C,D etc and generate the new value called Result and populate the A1 with it.

my code is

```
Function FindGrade(chkcell As String, Eventtype As String) As String
Dim A As String
Dim B As String
Dim C As String
Dim D1 As String
Dim D2 As String
Dim D3 As String

If chkevent = "Books" Then
A = "7"
B = "2,11"
C = "5"
D1 = "4"
D2 = "8,10,12"
D3 = "6"
End If


    
Dim Result As String

Dim x
Dim y
Dim chkfound
    'Updateby Extendoffice
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        .CompareMode = vbTextCompare
        For Each x In Split(chkcell, ",")
            For Each y In Split(A, ",")
            If x.exists(y) Then
            Result.Add "A"
            chkfound = 1
            Next y
        Next x
        
        If chkfound = 0 Then
        For Each x In Split(chkcell, ",")
            For Each y In Split(B, ",")
            If x.exists(y) Then
            Result.Add "B"
            chkfound = 1
            Next y
        Next x
        End If
        
        If chkfound = 0 Then
        For Each x In Split(chkcell, ",")
            For Each y In Split(C, ",")
            If x.exists(y) Then
            Result.Add "C"
            chkfound = 1
            Next y
        Next x
        End If
        
        If chkfound = 0 Then
        For Each x In Split(chkcell, ",")
            For Each y In Split(D1, ",")
            If x.exists(y) Then
            Result.Add "D1"
            chkfoundD = 1
            Next y
        Next x
        End If
        
        If chkfound = 0 Then
        For Each x In Split(chkcell, ",")
            For Each y In Split(D2, ",")
            If x.exists(y) Then
            Result.Add "D2"
            chkfoundD = 1
            Next y
        Next x
        End If
        
        If chkfound = 0 Then
        For Each x In Split(chkcell, ",")
            For Each y In Split(D3, ",")
            If x.exists(y) Then
            Result.Add "D3"
            chkfoundD = 1
            Next y
        Next x
        End If
        
        If chkfoundD = 0 Then
        For Each x In Split(chkcell, ",")
            For Each y In Split(D3, ",")
            If x.exists(y) Then
            Result.Add "3"
            chkfoundD = 1
            Next y
        Next x
        End If
        
        If chkfoundD = 0 Then
        For Each x In Split(chkcell, ",")
            For Each y In Split(D2, ",")
            If x.exists(y) Then
            Result.Add "2"
            chkfoundD = 1
            Next y
        Next x
            If chkfoundD = 0 Then
                Result.Add "1"
             End If
        
        End If
    End With

  
FindGrade = Result
End Function
```

Comment: I could not see a return value on `FindGrade` and `FindABCDEF` functions. https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/function-sub.html

Comment: Your question is unclear.  If H1 is dynamic, having code such as FindABCDEF with hardcoded values is counterproductive.  As Muzaffer pointed out, FindABCDEF doesn't do anything because your variables are limited in scope to the function itself.  If all you're doing is checking for the values in the letter variables, you could include that functionality in FindGrade.

Comment: @Tony...i m trying to generate A10 value based on H1 values by calling the function

Comment: Still not clear...  if H1 is "10,1,7,8", then what should the exact result of the function be?  That is, what value do you want to appear in A1?

Comment: in A1 i want it to be "A2" string @Tony" its shud check 10,1,7,8 first with each values in A,B,C,D1,D2,D3 generate the string...in this case it ill be A2

Comment: You must explain why it should be "A2" clearly. The solution will be easier if you explain what your goal is more clearly.

Comment: Some issues; 1) `H1` is processed in order of its contents, so you're not going to get an "A" result in the first position. Its first value of 10 equates to a "2" in your current code.  2) You have secondary conditional logic for variables `D2` and `D3` based upon a `chkfoundD` value.  You didn't specify inclusion/exclusion rules in your question, so it's impossible to debug.  I put a cleaner method of going through the contents of `H1` in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This might help get you on your way, but it's hard to decipher how you intend to derive the `FindGrade` result string.

It doesn't contain any assumption of conditional logic for the set of `D` values in the sample code but not specified in the question.

```
Function FindGrade(chkcell As String, Eventtype As String) As String

   Dim Result                                  ' Initialize variable
   Result = ""

   If Eventtype = "Book" Then
      For Each element In Split(chkcell, ",")  ' Evaluate each piece of chkcell
         Select Case element
            Case 7                             ' Condition A
               Result = Result & "A"
            Case 2, 11                         ' Condition B
               Result = Result & "B"
            Case 5                             ' Condition C
               Result = Result & "C"
            Case 4                             ' Condition D1
               Result = Result & "1"
            Case 8, 10, 12                     ' Condition D2
               Result = Result & "2"
            Case 6                             ' Condition D3
               Result = Result & "3"
         End Select
      Next element
   End If
    
   FindGrade = Result

End Function
```

Comment: The values in Case E.G Case 2, 11...r theses 2, 11 string? can i pass them in dynamically? as have it like Function FindGrade(chkcell As String, Eventtype As String,CC as String) and Case CC ...will it work?

Comment: @angel Why would you want to pass the condition into the function? At what point does logic determine the action to take?